# Append a folder name to a path variable in applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

```
set fold to "/Users/Test/Desktop/"
set file to "/Myfolder/Hi.txt"
```

How can I join these two variables to get my file path as "/Users/Test/Desktop//Myfolder/Hi.txt"?

Comment: Can your script be used as a contextual menu and lead to appending the folder to the path variable a simple one click?  Can you provide the full code for this potentially very useful applescript?

Answer (score 5):

here ya go

```
  set aFile to (the POSIX path of (path to desktop)) & "Myfolder/Hi.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Concatenation operator](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_operators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH5g-BAJEGEEC) to join strings:

```
set the folderPath to "/Users/Test/Desktop/"
set the filePath to "/Myfolder/Hi.txt"
set the fullPath to folderPath & filePath
```

Comment: this returns "/Users/Test/Desktop//Myfolder/Hi.txt" notice the double slashes you don't want that if you go with this method it will work find as long as you take out one of the slashes